# Website with central column : hide what's outside this column

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, swipe

I have this structure of swipe in my website: 
http://jsfiddle.net/bdfe70qu/1/

```
body {
   max-width: 100px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

---

```
<div id="pages">
  <div class="col-xs-6 tab">
  </div>        
  <div class="col-xs-6 tab">
  </div>        
</div>
```

I have a 100px width body and tabs that can swipe in this body.
I "just" need to hide the other tabs that are outside the 100px container.

Any insight ?

Thanks

Comment: See if this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/bdfe70qu/5/

Answer (score 2):

The CSS property and value you're looking for is `overflow: hidden`, but for this to work, you're going to need to apply it not only to the body, but also to the html element:

```
html, body {
    max-width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

## [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/bdfe70qu/3/)

Comment: Thanks, it works ! But in my code , I forgot to tell i have some widgets outside, like this http://jsfiddle.net/bdfe70qu/6/  Is there something we can do with them ?

Comment: I got it. I applied overflow: hidden to #pages and made zindex:1 when #widget has zindex : 2